# Unity Engine makes the sprite resolution terrible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, 2d-games

I'm new in gamedev and now trying my best in creating my first game. The problem is that i cannot understand why unity makes my sprites' resolution terrible. I've created a sprite which looks nice but once I try to start it in unity remote it hurts my eyes. I'll attach screenshots. I've read a lot about that problem but haven't found the solution yet.

[How it looks like in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bTD8.jpg)

[How I made it in AI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYHBq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Press on the sprite in Unity and change the compression to NONE, if it's still a bit blurry try to change the filter or the wrap mode. Make sure that your sprite is in Texture type: Sprite 2d and UI

Comment: It helped a bit but it's still far from how it should be. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: try to increase pixels per unit

Comment: i've already tried it too :D :(